# How many are possibilities to build count $n$ summing $k$ other counts?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

I have got an integer $n$. I have to build it by summing $k$, not necessary, different integers. Is there any overall formula to count how many are possibilities to build count $n$ summing $k$ other counts?

Every integers being summed have to be $\ge$ 0.

---

Example:

$n = 5$, $k=2$ : 1+4=5, 2+3=5, 5+0=5 --- score: 3

$n = 5$, $k=3$ : 1+1+3=5, 1+2+2=5, 1+4+0=5, 2+3+0=5, 5+0+0 --- score: 5

Comment: What are the scores for (5,3), (5,4), (5,5), (5,6)?

Comment: @kwak just added

Comment: you forgot 5+0+0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of summands doesn't matter, so you count 4+1 as equivalent to 1+4, then you need to count 'partitions of n into 2 parts'. This has no closed form formula, but it does have a nice recursion algorithm. See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts).

Answer (score 2):

This is called *combinations* of $n$.

Picture your integer $n$ as $n + k$ ones (so every summand is at least 1), separated by $k - 1$ plus signs, thus for $n = 5$ and $k = 3$ you are looking at, e.g.
$$
11+1+11111
$$
This is $2 + 1 + 5$, that means $1 + 0 + 4$ by subtracting the extra $k$ ones we added to have all non-empty stretches of ones. As there are $\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$ ways of distribuing the $k - 1$ plus signs among the $n + k - 1$ spaces between ones, your result follows.

This kind of argument is called *stars and bars*, by using $|$ and $*$ instead of ones and plus.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand fully your answer. For n=5 and k=2 binomial coefficient (5+2-1),(2-1) equals 30 - "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%285%2B2-1%29!%2F%28%282-1%29!*%285-1%29!%29" Wolfram Alpha, not 3 as should be in my example. Can you explain me that more?

Answer (score 0):

A fun way is to use generating functions. The generating function for $\mathbb{N}_0$ is just:
$$
N(z) = 1 + z + z^2 + \ldots = \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
The generating function for the ways of adding up $n$ by $k$ elements of $\mathbb{N}_0$ is then just:
$$
N^k(z) = \frac{1}{(1 - z)^k}
$$
and the corresponding coefficient is nothing more than:
$$
[z^n] N^k(z) = (-1)^n \binom{-k}{n} = \binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}
$$